# Disable button when time limit is reached

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking to disable a button when a time limit is reached. Currently, on my website it is set up that products have a count down timer active to show much time there is left to enter a competition. I would like to disable the product button once the timer has reached 0.

I had tried to do CSS on this but as the two attributes are in separate divs. I was not sure how to target them.

The button ID is `.button` and the "competition finished" ID is `.hasfinished`

Edit:
The html code for the finished competitions is:

```
<span class="has-finished">Competition Finished</span>
```

I had tried to target the button by using the following code:

```
.has-finished > .button { style="color:#777;background-color:#aaa;cursor:not-allowed;" }
```

which did not work so I then tried to do:

```
.has-finished ~ .button { style="color:#777;background-color:#aaa;cursor:not-allowed;"}
```

which did not work either.

The `.has-finished` is inside of a div above the `.button` attribute called `.astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap`

The countdown timer code is: `<dive class="lottery-time-countdown is-wc-lotery_countdown" data-time="1617228000" data-lotteryid="205177" data-format>`
`<span class="wc_lottery_countdown-row wc_lottery_countdown-show4">`

The button HTML code is `<a href="link"> data-quanity="1" class="button product_type_lottery" data-product_id="192520" data-product_sku aria-label="button"></a>`

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Please add the code what have you have tried yet. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry completely new to this! The html code for the finished competitions is: <span class="has-finished"> Competition Finished</span> I had tried to target the button by using the following code .has-finished > .button { style="color:#777;background-color:#aaa;cursor:not-allowed;" } which did not work so I then tred to do .has-finished ~ .button { style="color:#777;background-color:#aaa;cursor:not-allowed;"} which did not work either. The .has-finished is inside of a div above the .button attritubute called .astra-shop-thumbnail-wrap I hope this has made it clearer!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to find out what is expected of questions here. For questions asking for help with code, we like to see some code at least setting up the environment (in this case, the button and the countdown timer). Please [edit] your question to include the code; You can likely use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar) to make a runnable snippet to make it easier for others to reproduct.

Comment: <button id="some_button"> Click</button>

document.getElementById("some_button").disabled = true;

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some JS like

```js
$('.has-finished ~ .button').onclick = () => {};
$('.has-finished ~ .button').off();
```